# sbcl determine if symbolic link

Tags: common-lisp, symlink, sbcl

How do I test if a pathname is a symlink in sbcl?

```
CL-USER> (apropos "syml" )
:CLASSIFY-SYMLINKS (bound)
:RESOLVE-SYMLINKS (bound)
:SYMLINK (bound)
SB-IMPL::CLASSIFY-SYMLINKS
SB-IMPL::RESOLVE-PROBLEMATIC-SYMLINK
SB-IMPL::RESOLVE-SYMLINKS
SB-POSIX:SYMLINK (fbound)
UIOP/FILESYSTEM:*RESOLVE-SYMLINKS* (bound)
UIOP/FILESYSTEM:RESOLVE-SYMLINKS (fbound)
UIOP/FILESYSTEM:RESOLVE-SYMLINKS* (fbound)
UTIL::CLASSIFY-SYMLINKS
UTIL::SYMLINK
; No value
```

None of these appear useful. classify-symlinks seems to be a keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR

```
(defun symlinkp (pathname)
  (sb-posix:s-islnk (sb-posix:stat-mode (sb-posix:lstat pathname))))
```

To answer the question one has to first ask, how does one determine if something (a file descriptor I presume) is a symlink in posix. man 2 stat to the rescue. From the manpage

- > lstat() is  identical to  stat(), except that  if path  is asymbolic link, then the link itself is stat-ed, not the file that it refers to.
- > The following  POSIX macros  are defined  to check  the file type using the st_mode field:
- > S_ISLNK(m)  symbolic link?  (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)

Answer (score 0):

[osicat](https://common-lisp.net/project/osicat/manual/html_node/Files-and-Symbolic-Links.html) has the function `file-kind` which can detect symbolic links:

```
(ql:quickload "osicat")

(equalp :symbolic-link (osicat:file-kind "/some/path"))
```

Update: This function is buggy and doesn't work if you use `"/some/path/"`. (Note the trailing slash.)